# sqoop import staging table issue

Tags: hive, hiveql, sqoop

I am trying to import the data from teradata into HDFS location.
I have access to view for that database. So I created a staging table in another database. But when I try to run the code it says error

> Error: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.6.5.0-292 18/12/23 21:49:41 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead. 18/12/23 21:49:41 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import:staging-table, t_hit_data_01_staging, –clear-staging-table, --query, select * from table1 where cast(date1 as Date) <= date '2017-09-02' and $CONDITIONS, --target-dir, <>, --split-by, date1, -m, 25

I have given the staging table details in the code and ran it. but throws error.
(`Error parsing arguments from import and as un-recognized arguments from staging table`)

```
sqoop import \ 
--connect jdbc:teradata://<server_link>/Database=db01 \
--connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager \
--username <UN> \
--password <PWD> \
–-staging-table db02.table1_staging –clear-staging-table \
--query "select * from table1 where cast(date1 as Date) <= date '2017-09-02' and \$CONDITIONS " \
--target-dir '<hdfs location>' \
--split-by date1 -m 25`
```

The data should be loaded into the HDFS location, using the staging table in another database in Teradata.Then later on changing the where clause it sqoop should create another file under the same folder in HDFS location. Example: part-0000, next file as part -0001 etc.,

Comment: Can you post the error message that you have received here?

Comment: Error:
Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.6.5.0-292
18/12/23 21:49:41 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
18/12/23 21:49:41 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import:staging-table, t_hit_data_01_staging, –clear-staging-table, --query, select * from table1 where cast(date1 as Date) <= date '2017-09-02' and $CONDITIONS, --target-dir, <<hdfs location>>, --split-by, date1, -m,  25

Comment: thanks @Corion. I tried to add it to the question. It was giving error while submitting it.

Comment: it should be `--–clear-staging-table` and not `-clear-staging-table`

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a staging option available for import command.

https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.0-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html